# Related to scanf statements in c

Tags: c, scanf

I have come across the following piece of code and i'm not being able to understand the `scanf` portion.

```
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  scanf("%d %d"+scanf("%d %d",&i,&j));
  printf("%d %d",i,j);
  return 0;
}
```

I ran the code on inputs 4 8 9 and it returned 9 8.

Can someone please explain the working?

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles with gcc3.4.4.  This is very strange to me...

Comment: it isn't working for me

Comment: I think It's UB.

Comment: It's definitely undefined behaviour...

Comment: the inner `scanf` will be executed first, reads 4 and 8 into `i` and `j` and returns 2. After that the second `scanf` will be executed with `"%d %d"+2` without other parameters and so it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch which basically means the outer `scanf()` will get `" %d"` as a format string and try to scan an `int` for which there is no argument provided.

Comment: I get a crash normally when I don't supply the int arguments to `scanf(...)` however, this code doesn't seem to crash...

Comment: There's probably the address of `i` left on the stack (coincidently) from the previous `scanf()` call that gets accidently used as the address to scan the `int` to in the outer call.  But that's by no means guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Dmitri by most 64 bit calling conventions second argument is passed generally​ in a register. Very similar to what you said but different reasons.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya True... I considered saying, "on the stack or in a register" but didn't.  Though we don't really know what ABI this is using or whether it's 64-bit or not... and it's undefined behaviour regardless, so..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner `scanf("%d %d",&i,&j)` returns a count, like 2,1, EOF (or maybe 0).

Adding that count to the format string `"%d %d"`, offsets the format by the count, such as by 2, to form `" %d"`. This is simply pointer addition. [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355450/related-to-scanf-statements-in-c#comment73774549_43355610)

Then code does the equivalent of `scanf(" %d");` which is undefined behavior (UB) as it is missing a matching `int *` to go with the `" %d"`.  [@mch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355450/related-to-scanf-statements-in-c/43355610#comment73774247_43355450)

> Can someone please explain the working?

Its not "working", it is UB.

---

A variation that treads on [thin ice](https://storage.googleapis.com/media.mwcradio.com/cache-v2/42/93/42933fed201d2138913ebdfc31d9f72d.jpg).  It will "work" if the first `scanf()` returns 2.  Yet this all looks like hacker code to me.

```
int main() {
  int i,j;
  scanf("%d %d"+scanf("%d %d",&i,&j), &i);
  printf("%d %d",i,j);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does the + mean after "%d %d" ? we generally use ","  after format specifiers

Comment: @harshvardhan, it is the addition operator.  In this case, the operation involved is of the pointer + integer flavor. That's why chux says "Adding that count to the format string [...]."